# Meaning of a probability

Tags: probability

It is provided that 
$$P(X>a+b|X>a)=P(X>b)$$
Where $X$ is the random variable and $a,b$ are positive.

Explain the meaning of this equation in the case when $X$ is the number of days after treatment for a particular disease when a patient needs further treatment.

Can somebody please help me out in this? Moreover what is meant by "number of days after treatment for a particular disease when a patient needs further treatment"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > $$P(X>a+b\mid X>a)~=~P(X>b)$$
> >     Where $X$ is the random variable and $a,b$ are positive.
> >
> > Explain the meaning of this equation in the case when $X$ is the number of days after treatment for a particular disease when a patient needs further treatment.
>
> Can somebody please help me out in this? Moreover what is meant by "number of days after treatment for a particular disease when a patient needs further treatment"?

A patient needs further treatment for a diesease.   The number of days this treatment will be needed equals $X$.   After this number of days, the patient will not need further treatment.

$X>a$ is the event that this number is more than $a$.   $X>a+b$ is likewise the event that this number is more than the sum of $a$ and $b$.   What is $X>b~$?

Thus $P(X>b)$ is the probability that the patient will need more than $b$ days of further treatment.

$P(X>a+b\mid X>a)$ is the probability that the number needed will be greater than $a+b$ when given that it will be greater than $a$.   You could look at it as saying the probability that the patient will need an *additional* $b$ days of treatment after receiving $a$ days.

Now think about what the equality is saying about the process.

Comment: The equality is technically taking a to be 0, hence shifting the origin.

Comment: @FaiqRaees Moreover, the equality is saying that you *can* do that.  That the process is occuring in independent increments of time.

Comment: Oh yes, the function itself won't allow it. It's this memorylessness property of the function that is permitting it.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as [Memorylessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness). You effectively shift your origin to $a$ and restart the process, so it suffices to find when $X$ exceeds $b$. The most famous of these are the geometric and exponential distributions. So if you're waiting for a bus and 10 minutes have passed, the chance that you wait another 10 minutes is the same as if you start over. Knowing how much time has passed gives no information about how much longer you have to wait.

Comment: So basically we are talking about effectivity of the treatment. So even if we give the treatment no matter how many time, the probability the disease will be cured will remain same. Right?

Comment: Can you please explain the conditional probability related with memorylessness?

Answer (score 0):

The memoryless proeprty tells us about the conditional behavior of exponential random variables. It’s a key result in probability and has many implications. This type of problem shows up frequently in problems where we’re interested in the time between events.

It turns out that the conditional probability does not depend on $t$. The probability of an exponential random variable exceeding the value
$s+t$ given $t$ is the same as the variable originally exceeding that value
$s$, regardless of $t$

The exponential distribution is memoryless because the past has no bearing on its future behavior. Every instant is like the beginning of a new random period, which has the same distribution regardless of how
much time has already elapsed.

The exponential is the only memoryless continuous random variable.

In your case the memoryless distribution has these implications:
If "$X$ is the number of days after treatment for a particular disease when a patient needs further treatment", then because the distribution is memoryless, past doses have no bearing on its efficacy in the future. In other words, every time some patient takes the medication, it's like the first time they are taking it.

As a counter example, consider the Pareto distribution, which is not memoryless. The Pareto distribution (is one of many distributions that) has the property that the expected wait time actually INCREASES the longer you have to wait. This is an excellent model for cancer survival - a person who survives 6 months after treatment has a much longer expected lifespan that someone who is just beginning treatment.

That is, if 
$$f(x) = C/(x+a)^n\ \text{for $x > 0$},$$

then

$$f(x - d|X > d) = K/(x + a + d)^n$$

If we compare this survival model with that of the exponential distribution, it is NOT an particularly good model for cancer survival - a person who survives 6 months after treatment has an equivalent lifespan that someone who is just beginning treatment.

Answer (score 0):

the math is saying that the chances of X being greater than a+b when X is already greater than a is the same as the chance that X is greater than b.  In other words, X's relationship to a is not relevant.  In treatment terms, this is saying that the chances of a treatment being efficacious at some time point when it has already been efficacious at some earlier time point is the same as the chance of of being efficacious now.  I probably didn't put that very well, but basically it's like getting the treatment for the first time.  An example would be using a band-aid for a cut.  How well it works now is not related to how well it worked when you cut your finger in the Great Pizza Party of '09.